# Collection View/Tab Bar Controller Crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

In my app, I am using a Tab Bar controller to switch between view controllers, and on each view controller I am using a collection view to then go on to different pages.  When I run the app on the computer, everything works fine.  The issue is when I run the app on my phone.  Whenever I click on a tab in the tab bar controller that goes to a page with a collection view controller on it, the app freezes and then crashes. I think that I have narrowed down the issue to the collection view controller, because the app on my phone doesn't crash when there is no collection view controller.  It only crashes when the collection view controller is in use.  What might be causing this? I have looked, but haven't found any similar issues.

Here is the code for one of the collection view controllers:

```
import UIKit
class HighSchoolController: UIViewController, \UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var identities = [String]()

    let hsImage: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "dates")!,
        UIImage(named: "athletics_icon")!,
        UIImage(named: "interm-1")!,
        UIImage(named: "lunch_icon")!,
        UIImage(named: "pioneerpress")!,
        UIImage(named: "PIONEERNEWS")!,
        UIImage(named: "clubs_icon")!,
        UIImage(named: "contact_icon")!
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        identities = ["events", "athletics", "da", "lunch", "pioneer press", "pioneer news", "clubs", "contact"]

        //Navigationbar Shadow
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 4.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 9.0
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hsImage.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let hsCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "hsCell", for: indexPath) as! HighSchoolCell


        hsCell.hsImage.image = hsImage[indexPath.item]

        hsCell.layer.cornerRadius = (hsCell.layer.frame.height) / 2.0;
        hsCell.layer.masksToBounds = true

        return hsCell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: attach the crash log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by doing this in my tabbar Controller

- let layout1  =   UICollectionViewFlowLayout()  let cv1 =
  CollectionView1(collectionViewLayout: layout1)
- let layout2  =   UICollectionViewFlowLayout() 
  let cv2 = CollectionView1(collectionViewLayout: layout2)
- let layout3 = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  let cv3 = CollectionView1(collectionViewLayout: layout3)
- let layout4  =   UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  let cv4 = CollectionView1(collectionViewLayout: layout4)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that it must be crashing on your `self.navigationController?...` lines. My guess is that you are using the `CollectionViewController` as the `rootViewController` of the tab in the `TabBarController`.

If you want to use a `navigationController` to navigate within a tab, you need to attach a `navigationController` as the root of a tab, and then set the `CollectionViewController` as the `rootViewController` of the `navigationController`.

Instead of a hierarchy of `TabBarController > CollectionViewController`, you need one like `TabBarController > NavigationViewController > CollectionViewController`